# Проходят не все тесты c++

Tags: c++, функции

Нужно написать функцию, вычисляющую длину отрезка по координатам его концов. С помощью этой функции вычислить периметр треугольника по координатам трех его вершин.
Все числа по модулю не превосходят 30000.
значение периметра этого треугольника с точностью до 6 знаков после десятичной точки.
Вот моя программа, проходит 25/32 тестов. Что нужно исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
double L (int x, int y ,int x1, int y1)
{
return sqrt( ( x- x1 )*( x- x1 ) + ( y-y1 )*( y-y1 ));
}
long int a,b,c,d,e,f;
double s1,s2,s3,s,p,P;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f;
    s1=L(a,b,c,d);
    s2=L(c,d,e,f);
    s3=L(e,f,a,b);
    P=s1+s2+s3;
    cout<<P;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А координаты входные - целые числа?

Comment: Да, целые числа

Comment: "до 6 знаков после десятичной" - где?

Comment: Выводит до 6 знаков)

Comment: Что "выводит до 6 знаков"? Где в коде Вы контролируете количество цифр после десятичного разделителя в выводимом числе?

Comment: Это не требуется

Comment: Тип double, если что

Comment: А зачем Вы тогда написали в вопросе "c точностью до 6 знаков после десятичной точки"?

Comment: x1=30000, x2=-30000 - что будет под корнем? если бы был беззнаковый инт, то уложились бы... а так 3.6 миллиарда вроде не вписывается

Comment: Сравните: **long int** a,b,c,d,e,f; и почему-то double L (**int** x, **int** y ,**int** x1, **int** y1)

Comment: А с интом также

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Юлия, попробуйте вместо своей функции L() такую и прогоните тесты с ней:

```
double L (int x, int y ,int x1, int y1)
{
   double x2 = (double)( x-x1 )*( x-x1 );
   double y2 = (double)( y-y1 )*( y-y1 );
   return sqrt( x2 + y2 );
}
```

PS: да, приведение типа можно было и под sqrt() положить. Но так нагляднее. И вместо `double` для промежуточных значений можно брать и `long int`.

PPS: да, в современном С++ принято приводить типы другими словами. Но так компактнее и "на скорость не влияет".

PPPS: и еще, раз у Вас есть ограничение на входные значения, то Вы должны их проверять при вводе.

Comment: привидение типа надо делать ДО умножения... А вообще говоря и в функцию предавать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, в данном случае оно и будет сделано ДО умножения. Насколько помню, такое приведение типа относится к следующему за ним операнду, а не ко всей строке. Про функцию - да, хорошо бы передавать сразу. Но в задании может быть ограничение на аргументы - нам об этом не сообщали. Поэтому я изменил минимум.

Comment: да, прошу прощения... меня переклинило...